# Looping through each character in a string, then replacing the said character with acronyms, without using replace() or find() functions

Tags: python-3.x

I have this code so far, I am wondering how to approach this problem:

---

```
def phrase(trans):
        replacePHR = ["As soon as possible", "On the way", "Right now", "Okay"]
        replaceACR = ["ASAP", "OTW", "RN", "KK"]        

       for i in (len(trans)):
            if len(trans[i:len(trans)] >= (len(replacePHR[0]))):
                if trans[i:i + len(replacePHR[0])] == replacePHR[0]:
                    phr = trans[0:i] + replaceACR[0]
                    trans[i + len(replacePHR[0]): len(trans)]
            return phr

       phr = input("\nDo you want to replace phrases? ")
            if (phr == "yes"):
                phr = phrase(trans)
                print(phr)
            else:
                continue
```

Comment: What does "without using built-in functions" mean? Isn't `len` a built-in function, for example?

Comment: Can you please check the indentation of your code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. As mentioned, your question is not very clear, and your code is invalid. Please [edit] to clarify and fix it. See [ask] for other advice.

Comment: @kaya3 I am referring to functions like replace() and find(), I need to make a loop to check through the string and replace the parts

Comment: That's not very specific; we don't know which functions you consider to be too much "like" `replace` and `find`, and which functions you consider different enough that they are allowed.

Comment: For example, I can simulate a replace using `acronym.join(sentence.split(phrase))`; are `join` and `split` too much like `replace` and `find`?

Comment: @kaya3 Those are allowed

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowed to use `join` and `split`, then it's very easy to do a replace: `split` breaks the sentence apart on each occurrence of a search string, and `join` joins them together with a different string.

Essentially, `a.join(s.split(b))` does the same thing as `s.replace(a, b)`, just without calling any of your proscribed built-in functions.

```py
def replace_acronyms(s):
    replacements = {
        "As soon as possible": "ASAP",
        "On the way": "OTW",
        "Right now": "RN",
        "Okay": "KK",
    }

    for phrase, acronym in replacements.items():
        s = acronym.join(s.split(phrase))

    return s
```

Usage:

```py
>>> replace_acronyms("Are you coming? As soon as possible. Okay, see you soon!")
'Are you coming? ASAP. KK, see you soon!'
```

This is a very strange set of problem constraints, but since you've said `join` and `split` are allowed, then this is a solution. It does seem like it subverts the intention of whoever set the problem.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, the specifications are not clear, hence why it was not clear from me, but I think your way works out

Comment: Is there any way I could reach you(E-Mail preferred), I would like some further assistance, please.

Answer (score -1):

You should use a dictionary! Below is something to get you started

```
def phrase(trans):
    translations = {
        "ASAP":"As soon as Possible",
        "OTA":"On the Way",
        "G2G":"Got to Go"
        }

    new_string = translations[trans]

    return(new_string)
```

Comment: Wouldn't `translations.get()` be a *built-in function* that the poster says they can't use?

Comment: Okay, changed it to new_string = translations[trans].

Comment: I have set them to a dictionary in my new code, I now have problems looping through the actual strings and checking

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question; it's more of a tangential suggestion.

Comment: @kaya3 No, I meant like I have specific restrictions, I can' t use replace or find